# On improper Riemann integral

Tags: real-analysis

Let $F:R \to (0,1)$ be a strictly increasing continuous distribution function such that $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}xdF(x)<\infty$. Let $(x_k)_{k \in N}$ be a sequence of uniformly distributed numbers in $(0,1)$. Prove the validity of the following equality
$$
\int_{0}^1F^{-1}(x)dx=\lim_{n \to \infty}\frac{\sum_{k=1}^n F^{-1}(x_k)}{n}.
$$

Answer (score 1):

**The independence of the random variables $\{x_i\}$ will be assumed.**

Notice that $F$ is the common distribution function of the independent random variables $X_i=F^{-1}(x_i)$. So the following average is approaching the common expectation of the $X_i$'s, which exists:

$$\lim_{n \to \infty}\frac{\sum_{k=1}^n F^{-1}(x_k)}{n}= \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}x\ dF(x)<\infty\tag1$$

a.s.

If $ \{x_i\} $ are independent random variables uniformly distributed over $(0,1)$ then

$$\lim_{n \to \infty}\frac{\sum_{k=1}^n F^{-1}(x_k)}{n} \tag2$$

is the limit of a quasy random Riemann sum of $F^{-1}$ over $(0,1)$. (Think that $(0,1)$ is divided into $n$ sub-intervals of length $1/n$.)   The limit exists by $(1)$ so $(2)$ cannot be different from the limit of any Riemann sum with well chosen $x_i$'s. (Well chosen means that the sub intervals contain only one $x_i$.)

Comment: The validity of the Law of Large  numbers implies the validity of the  equality  above for almost  infinite  samples  uniformly distributed in $(0,1)$  but no for each  uniformly distributed sequence $(x_k)$.

Comment: @GogiPantsulaia: What is a uniformly distributes sequence? Do you mean that $x_0=1/n$, $x_1=2/n,\cdots$?

Comment: A sequence $s_1, s_2, s_3, \cdots$ of real numbers of $(0.1)$  is said
to be equidistributed or uniformly distributed on an interval $[0,1]$ if for any subinterval $[c, d]$ of the $[0,1]$ we have
$\lim_{n \to \infty}\#(\{s_1, s_2, s_3, \cdots, s_n\} \cap
[c,d]) / n=d-c$, where $\#$ denotes a counting measure.

Comment: @GogiPantsulaia:  Oh, well. Then my answer, however smart an answer it is :), is not an answer to your question. I can imagine, however, that using such a sequence when defining the Riemann integral of $F^{-1}$ over $(0,1)$ could be used to define of the Riemann-Stieltjes integral with $y_i=F^{-1}(x_i)$. Then a substitution of $u=F(x)$ would lead to the required result. I would be glad to do that exercise but I have a party to attend. If I will be sober then I will go on after that.

Comment: @GogiPantsulaia: One more comment before disappearing for good: If $x_i$ is a sequence of independent random variables uniformly distributed over $(0,1)$ then then the sequence of random numbers resulted are uniformly distributed (in your sense) with probability one. Unfortunately you seem not to be satisfied with such a result.

Comment: The positive answer to my question implies the validity of the SLLN in our case.

Comment: I have no seen estimations to my answer. Is my answer so difficult for understanding?

Comment: @GogiPantsulaia, no no, I understand your question. To be honest I haven't been in good shape  lately. Thank you for your message. I will try to do something.

Comment: @Jack'swastedlife : Above is a problem that may be interesting for you.

Comment: @  zoli,  Thank you in advance